# how can solve a algorithm about counter unbalance and overlaps method?

Tags: java, libgdx, counter

hello i am trying make 2d game using libgdx.
to sum up i have two rectangle and i am checking to collision.
i want increase counter for example 1,2,3,4,5,6...
but counter increasing unbalance as a result if's not working.
because counter increase for example 34,49,78....
two rectangles intersect and overlap continues as a result counter increase unbalance. I want After the first intersection don't increase the counter.
i am thinking to function instead of overlaps but no result 
for this i need your help.

By the way counter is global variable. first counter's value is 0. And game have a endless loop. game work like flappybird. But gamer have 3 life.

Code is here:

```
if(xRectangle.overlaps(yRectangle)) {
    counter++;
    if (counter == 1)
       bang.play();
    if (counter == 2)
       bang.play(); 
    if (counter == 3) {
       System.out.println("game finished!");
       bang.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your game when the counter value is increasing in an unbalanced manner because Collision detection checked by the libgdx is at the rate of 1/60 fps. So in each nanosecond, it will increase the counter during the collision . To avoid this, I suggesting you to do a small modification in your code.

```
          int countController=0;
          if(xRectangle.overlaps(yRectangle)) {
          countController++;
          if(countController%60==0){
              counter++;
          if (counter == 1)
          bang.play();
          if (counter == 2)
          bang.play(); 
          if (counter == 3) {
          System.out.println("game finished!");
          bang.play();
          }
          }
          }
```

// please try this code. All the best